# Web Parse VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Im tring to webparse some website but what im getting is a warn that tells me to turn on
javascript.
In order to bypass it I need to use WebBrowser but this method taking a lot of RAM when doing 18 requests it can go up to 3GB of ram  .

```
   Try
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(TextBox1.Text)
        Request.Proxy = Nothing
        Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"

        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse
        Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream

        Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
        Dim Data As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
        StreamReader.Close()
        RichTextBox1.Text = Data
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
```

Output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="/vddosw3data.js"></script>
<body>
<div w3-include-html="/5s.html"></div>
<noscript><h1 style="text-align:center;color:red;"><strong>Please turn JavaScript on and 
reload the page.</strong></h1></noscript>
<script>
```

Is there anyway to baypass it without using a webbrowser?

Comment: Is this you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69440615/3043 If so, please don't post duplicates.

Comment: If you create WebBrowser objects (which browser? There's nothing related to the use of any browser here) for each *request* you create - as you're doing now with the `WebResponse` - then it's quite possible that the memory usage will grow quickly. -- When an object exposes a `Dispose()` method, you really need to call it; or declare your objects with `Using` statements.